# Refer related model field in model layer

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I am try to refer 'spot_price' of model 'Spot' in model 'Basis' in django model layer, How can I manage this?

I have designed view.py to automaticaly render the templates. so I am not able to modifty any view.py to choose data like 'models.B.objects.get().field'.

and more, **str** is set to indicate the date, so, in the django backstage admin, the 'spot' field display would be 'date' formate, how would be change to 'spot_price'?

model Spot

```
class Spot(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    spot_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) if self.date else ''
```

need to refer the model Spot'spot_price by date, cause date is unique but spot_price is not

```
class Basis(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    major_future_contract_close_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    spot = models.OneToOneField(Spot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    basis = models.FloatField(default=calculate_basis)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) if self.date else ''

    def calculate_basis(self):
        return abs(self.major_future_contract_close_price - 
        self.spot.spot_price)
```

I expect the Basis.query.data would to like 'date: 2019-04-25, major_future_contract_close_price: 100.0, spot: 96.5, basis: 3.5'

Comment: Do you want to change `Spot` str only for `OneToOneField` in `Basis`? Do you need to refer `spot_price` for `calculate_basis`?

Comment: Exactly, I only need ```spot_price``` in this ```Basis``` model, while in other model, I prefer ```date``` as str. ```calculate_basis``` requires ```spot_price``` field in ```Spot``` model.

Comment: ```calculate_basis``` refer both ```spot_price``` and ```major_future_contract_close_price``` in same ```date```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use class method as default, because it requires `self`, which is not existing when you are still creating the object.

If you need to have it stored in field (database), [override default `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) or use [`signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) to modify the `basis` field once your object is created. Also note that you have to recalculate basis every time `close_price` or `spot_price` changes, as the value is just written in database.

Probably better solution would be to use [`@property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods) so for anyone that will be using you model it will look like a field, but it will dynamically calculate value based on current data.

For example, I'm overriding `save()` to calculate the `basis` field. I set it as `editable=False`, which means it won't appear in forms by default (and you will not be able to see it in admin!). You can safely remove that part if you want to just look at the values.
Additionally I add `basis_as_property` property.

```py
class Basis(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    major_future_contract_close_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    spot = models.OneToOneField(Spot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    basis = models.FloatField(editable=False, blank=True)

    @property
    def basis_as_property(self):
        return '%s' % (self.calculate_basis())

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) if self.date else ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.basis:
            self.basis = self.calculate_basis()
        super(Basis, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def calculate_basis(self):
        return abs(self.major_future_contract_close_price - self.spot.spot_price)
```

As for `Spot` str repr, I don't think it's possible to change it based on where it is referenced. If you want to use `spot_price`, you can just use: `return str(self.spot_price) if self.spot_price else str(self.date)`

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with stackoverflow yet, thought you might not seen my reply. what I only is the ```spot_price``` in this ```Basis``` model, while in other model, I prefer ```date``` as str. ```calculate_basis``` method requires ```spot_price``` and ```major_future_contract_close_price``` with the same ```date```